# ClickOnce upgrades leaving early versions on disk

Tags: deployment, clickonce

There seems to be a problem with ClickOnce deployments.

The manifest file is executed on the client machine, and there's a check to see if a new version is available. If a new version is available, this gets copied over to the client machine. BUT the old version remains.

This can be a problem. If the application is upgraded on a regular basis, this will end up occupying a large and continually growing disk space. This could be a problem at a work place where multiple users all logged on to the same Citrix server.

Is there a straightforward solution to ClickOnce not cleaning up after itself? Is there some setting that I'm missing?

---

**Later Edit**
This question actually states something that's incorrect. In reality ClickOnce upgrades only leave the previous version behind, and versions before that are cleaned up. I'll leave the question here (as opposed to deleting it) as this is a misunderstanding that others could have as well.

Comment: Are you seeing more than one old version per user? By default, you get a Program & Features option to rollback one version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft Click once does clean up after itself however it will always leave the previous one version behind to enable roll-back functionality.

see http://www.sayedhashimi.com/PermaLink,guid,520010a7-6ce7-47ec-af0f-a57694bf3d41.aspx for more info.

Comment: Ah. I just tested this by upgrading five times, and when I search my Apps directory there are only ever two installations. My mistake.